# random generator question,how the rpois(a,b) performed when b is a vector?

Tags: r

I just wondering how the rpois(a,b) performed when b is a vector?

for example

```
m <- rgamma(1000, 10, 1)
j <- rpois(1000, m)
```

Can anyone tell me how the J performs? Is it run a loop on m and generate 1 random variable every time?

Thank you

Comment: It is vectorized for the `lambda` as it takes a vector of values.  You can check it with `j1 <- integer(length(m)); set.seed(24);for(i in seq_along(m)) j1[i] <- rpois(1, m[i]);identical(j, j1)#
[1] TRUE`

Comment: so my understanding is right? It takes every single m and generates 1 random number, what if the length is different, for example,m<-rgamma(100,10,1)
j<-rpois(1000,m)

Comment: I think there is a recycling going on i.e. `identical(head(j, 100), head(j1, 100))#
[1] TRUE` and 
`identical(head(j, 101), head(j1, 101))#
[1] FALSE`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function is vectorized for the `lamdba` as according to `?rpois`

> lamdba - vector of (non-negative) means.

It can be tested with the same seed

```
set.seed(24)
j <- rpois(1000, m)
```

Now, we do this in a loop

```
j1 <- integer(length(m))
set.seed(24)
for(i in seq_along(m)) j1[i] <- rpois(1, m[i])
```

check for equality

```
identical(j, j1)
#[1] TRUE
```

---

For the second case of a different `length` for `lambda`, the 'm' values are recycled once it reaches every 100 values i.e. the 'm' is repeated for each block of 100 or repeated 10 times

```
m <- rgamma(100,10,1)
set.seed(24)
j <- rpois(1000, m)
```

To test this, we replicate the 'm' values to make the length same

```
m1 <- rep(m, length.out = 1000)
j1 <- integer(1000)
set.seed(24)
for(i in seq_along(m1)) j1[i] <- rpois(1, m1[i])
```

check for equality

```
identical(j, j1)
#[1] TRUE
```